# spring cloud config server crashed when called /health endpoint frequently

Tags: crash, out-of-memory, config, spring-cloud

I deployed a spring cloud config server on cloud Foundry. To get its health status in real time, I called its /health endpoint every minute. But after a few days later, config server crashed(**out of memory**). The chart of memory usage shows that the percentage of memory usage increased stably until it reached 100%. if I did not call /health endpoint so frequently, it ran normally. There seemed to be memory leak. Why did this happened?

this is the pom.xml file of config server maven project:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Dalston.SR1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

this is the only java code in the config server project:

```
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

this is the application.properties file in the config server project:

```
spring.application.name=config-server

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/***/config-server-test
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=zhu*****
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=****
```

Comment: I believe we've been working on this on a github issue. I don't want to duplicate effort.